# Как вставить(экранировать) переменную в место перед точкой JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, синтаксис, экранирование

В переменной `itemNumber` хранится число
Есть объекты типа `cart.name1.price`, `cart.name2.price`

Как поместить/подставить переменную на место числа? Может как-то экранировать надо?

`cart.name+itemNumber+.price` - ругается на точку после `+`

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что это костыль, верно? У вас формат объекта `cart` явно не совпадает с вашими нуждами.

Comment: должна быть такая структура {cars:[car:{name:'Volvo',price:30000},car:{name:'BMW',price:35000}]} от car в данном случае лучше избавится

Comment: `var name = 'name'+itemNumber; console.log(cart[name].price)`

Comment: Cтруктура такая, если есть замечания по поводу реализации, выслушаю предложения.
`name1:{
        volume1:{
            name:"111",
            volume:"0,9",
            price:"100"
        }
    },
    name2:{
        volume1:{
            name:"222",
            volume:"0,9",
            price:"100"
        }
    }`

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich не путайте `car` и `cart` :) Идея правильная, разве что в массивах явно указывать ключи нет смысла, но буду считать, что это оговорка.

Comment: @D-side А как тогда к ним обращаться без явного индекса?

Comment: А по какому признаку вы собрались выбирать какую-то конкретную запись из контейнера, не имея её индекса?

Comment: @D-side По data атрибуту присваивается индекс.

Comment: То есть, явный индекс у вас всё-таки есть? ._.

Comment: @D-side Так есть. Вопрос же выше был о том как к нему обращаться. Выбрал тот метод исполнения который показался более очевидным в данной задаче. Хотя сейчас вроде бы и это понял.

Comment: Я говорил про код @SergeEsmanovich, который вообще синтаксически неверен, но содержит правильную идею. У массивов есть числовые индексы, при обращении, конечно, их надо использовать прямо. Их указывать в **литералах** невозможно (да и бессмысленно).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Для этого надо использовать [скобочную нотацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

```
cart["name"+itemNumber].price
```