# Как обратиться к свойству объекта, в имени которого есть пробелы?

Tags: javascript, handlebars

```
var obj_ = {
    a : 1,
    "олег соколов" : 2
};
```

В handlebars

```
{{this.a}} // вернет 1

{{this.олег соколов}} // ошибка
```

Comment: Попробуйте `{{this['олег соколов']}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если ваш идентификатор содержит пробел или любые символы из списка

```
! " # % & ' ( ) * + , . / ; < = > @ [ \ ] ^ ` { | } ~
```

Вам необходимо заключить идентификатор в квадратные скобки:

```
{{this.[foo bar]}}
```

И да, точка перед открывающей скобкой обязательна :)

Comment: пока не написал про точку, хотел как дубль закрыть про bracket notation, но тут похоже что-то еще :)

Comment: @Grundy ссылочку на дубль можно?

Comment: Я обычно закрываю одним из: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/494534/186999), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/481964/186999), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/552422/186999)

Comment: @Grundy, прочитай вопрос по-внимательнее. Речь не о JS, а о Handlebars.

Comment: Ну так о чем и речь :-)